# Accessing geolocked API using Node & Axios

Tags: node.js, express, axios, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying accessing the [CoWIN](https://apisetu.gov.in/public/marketplace/api/cowin#/) API from an Express server that is deployed on Heroku - US region (I am a free user and they only provide access to US & EU regions in the free tier). The issue is that the API is deployed on CloudFront and is geofenced i.e., only accessible from an Indian IP. I have tried using a [npm package](https://github.com/saran-surya/cassata) that uses proxy but that requires my browser to be always connected to my server (not ideal). Is there a workaround (preferably free) that allows me to mock my server's IP or proxy or anything that bypasses this geofencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had faced this same issue while **DevOpsifying** a vaccine notifier application using Express & Telegram API.

Since Heroku free tier is only available in US & EU regions, I first switched to a Ubuntu Droplet on Digital Ocean (I chose the Bangalore Data Center) but this didn't work (using free credits). I am not sure why the calls to the API were blocked despite being an Indian IP.

Finally, using AWS Free Tier creating an EC2 Instance in `ap-south-1` Mumbai region WORKED!

This is a simple workaround that worked for me, I would suggest you try this first. Other workarounds are complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I'll accept the answer if it works for me. Cheers.

Comment: While calling the API, add a `user-agent` header which would mock the request as if it's coming from a browser, rather than a script.

Comment: Eg. headers: {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36"}

Comment: Yes, this works locally, in fact, I am using it in my code currently. But the issue is when I deploy it to Heroku. I have tried fetching the request using Tor Browser with Netherland as location and it gives me 403 Forbidden, the same one I get when I deploy.

Comment: Using AWS Free Tier, create an EC2 instance in the `ap-south-1` Mumbai region. Deploy your app onto it, now the API calls should work.

Comment: I've written a blog post regarding MERN/Node.js app AWS deployment, In case you want to refer - [link](https://blog.jagankaartik.live/devops/aws/cloud/2021/05/02/deploy-mern-aws/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The article is quite good too. I'll try this soon !

Comment: Blog Post [Updated-Link](https://blog.jagankaartik.com/posts/nodejs-aws-indepth-guide/)